# Multiple Constructors in Java,

Tags: java

In Java when you create a new object with multiple constructors, does it basically go in order? For example, what if you had a constructor with multiple ints? Or what if you wanted to skip a constructor argument? Would it even execute?

Comment: *"does it basically go in order"* go what in what order? You can *easily* try this out for yourself and get answers to all the questions.

Comment: Is your question about the `this(<constructor args>)`? The order varies on the supplied argument.

Comment: Did you try a web search for [`java multiple constructors`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+multiple+constructors)? It would have answered your question.

Answer (score 6):

Each constructor is independent of the others. The constructor which gets to build the object is the one you invoke after the `new` operator.

Comment: "independent of the others" unless you call `this(...)` on the first line.

Answer (score 0):

```
    which constructor to call depends upon arguments you pass, for example lets consider following class:

    public class Animal
    {
    String name;
    String type;
    Boolean carnivorous;

    Animal(String name)
    {
    this.name = name;
    }

    Animal(String name, String Type)
    {
    this.type = type;
    this.name = name;
    }
    }

    so if you pass name and type Animal(String name, String Type) will be called , or if you pass only name then Animal(String name) will be called. 
Also make note that if you define your own constructor then you override no-argument default constructor, so if you need that too along with your custom constructors then define it simply as
  Animal();
```